# How do I alter a form using an AJAX callback?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have this callback function triggered by an `onChange()` event in another select box.
This code, however, doesn't make the field enabled

```
public static function changeForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) : array {
  $form['field_my_custom_field']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax Forms in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7) states:

> Changes to the form must only be made in the form builder function. The callback function must not alter the form or any other state.

In form build/alter, check `$form_state->getTriggeringElement()` for the triggering element and then enable the field.

Comment: In my case, I have two custom fields. It's the same ?

Comment: @AlessioFrabotta It's also valid for custom fields, independently from how many they are.