# How to alter form after doBuildForm call during AJAX response

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm altering a form defined by a contrib module. Recently, that module switched to AJAX and my form alter isn't applied during the AJAX response. I believe the problem is in the following code used by that contrib for rebuilding the form during AJAX response callback:

```
$new_form = $this->buildForm($form, $form_state);
$new_form = $this->formBuilder->doBuildForm($this->getFormId(), $new_form, $form_state);
$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#enroll-wrapper', $new_form['enroll_wrapper']));
return $response;
```

This leads to this execution order:

1. the form plugin `buildForm()` method
2. my `form_alter` hook
3. my `after_build` callback which I've tried to mitigate the issue
4. the form plugin `buildForm()` method **again**

This confuses me, because I got info, that [D7 workflow](https://www.drupal.org/files/fapi_workflow_7.x_v1.3.png) basically still applies. How can I apply my modifications in this case? Please let me know, if you need more info.

Comment: Normally you don't need the two lines building $new_form, in the Ajax workflow the form is already rebuilt when the ajax callback is called. The only thing the ajax callback has to do is to make sure the right parts of the DOM are replaced. What if you remove the two lines and use $form? If the contrib module is still working I would submit an issue.

Comment: Thanks, @4uk4. I suspect the reason is that the buildForm logic is complicated and needs to be fully evaluated when the AJAX request is made. There's one interesting detail - as you can see in the form plugin code (https://github.com/goalgorilla/open_social/blob/ee688831e7377f5e8fa15af9d2fa8af4bd387e19/modules/social_features/social_event/src/Form/EnrollActionForm.php#L526), `submitForm` method is completely empty, which contradicts info in article about handling AJAX in Drupal Forms (https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-form-api-ajax-form-and-results-same-page).

Comment: I've tried to remove these 2 lines and added `setRebuild` to `submitForm` method. The problem remains, `buildForm` method is still called as the last.

Comment: setRebuild has no effect in Ajax requests, there the form is rebuilt automatically. You set this as fallback if Ajax is not working because the client doesn't support javascript. In the same context the ajax callback should not contain any form logic. It just defines a different delivery method replacing what setRebuild would do in a non Ajax submit.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. When I removed these 2 lines, my form_alter hook evaluated after the form plugin buildForm method, but then the state changes don't work correctly - which means this solution needs rebuilding to be present.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. You can't change any state in an ajax callback. This is only a delivery method. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269257/how-do-i-alter-a-form-using-an-ajax-callback